# Acumatica report errors for Sales Profitibility

Tags: report, acumatica

I am trying to create a Sales Profitability by Customer Class and Item report using report designer. After including the table names in the Value field of Report designer this error is shown for Item column[image: this error]

[image]

Do I need to make changes to this screen to? [image]

[image]

There is a table named InventoryItem having field InventoryCD in the database and I have used it in other reports too. But in this particular report it is giving error. Am I missing out something?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the table relationships in the build schema?

Comment: Oh right! I didn't add Inventory table to the relationships.
Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: What should be the relationship between Customer and InventoryItem table in this case? Since I am trying to create Sales profitability by customer class and item? I have included Screenshot in my question

Comment: There should be relationship between ARTran and InventoryItem table I think...but I tried connecting these 2 tables but still the values aren't right in the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After linking ARTran to InventoryItem on the InventoryID, you need to update the group collection to InventoryItem.InventoryID. 
[image]
[image]